# Query to get select data inside query using Grouped By

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a not so simple (maybe simple) MySQL query question.

I am trying to get results like so:

[users][disabled_users][venue_name]

So results would be like so:

5, 2, AABB

2, 0, ABCC

The results I am getting are:

5, 2, AABB

2, 2, ABCC <-- Issue is it finds the 2 results regardless

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT
count(t.uid) as users, /* GET COUNT OF ACTIVE USERS GROUPED BY VENUE ID*/ 
t3.vid as venue_id /* SOLUTION */   
(
    SELECT sum(t1.uid) as users /* GET COUNT OF DISABLED USERS GROUPED BY VENUE ID */
    FROM t1
    JOIN t2 ON (t1.sid = t2.id)
    JOIN t3 ON (t2.cid = t3.id)
    WHERE t1.tid = 3 AND t3.vid = venue_id /* SOLUTION */
    GROUP BY t3.vid
) as disabledUsers
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON (t1.sid = t2.id)
JOIN t3 ON (t2.cid = t3.id)
WHERE t1.tid = 2
GROUP BY t3.vid;
```

EDIT: The solution is marked by the /* SOLUTION */ I added two lines one selecting the venue id (vid) giving it an alias of venue_id and adding an extra condition in my inner select.

Comment: we also have an very simple request... you could also post an example on SQLfriddle with create tables statements and example data and result data

Comment: SQLFiddle is currently down.

Comment: You should also post that information here offcource..

Comment: Also I solved this. Read my edit for the resolution.